# NinePatch images does not stretch

Tags: android, nine-patch

I've created this nine patch image.

[image]

I've used it as button background. In the button I've also put a text "back", but here is the result.

[image]

How can I put a text to the right of the arrow and let the image stretches in order to fit it? 
(Don't worry about it's pixelated)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all as I can see you are creating the image in the wrong way. You can use this tool  [link](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/nine-patches.html)  . It's very useful at first steps.

Second of all in my opinion just remove that arrow from the background image. Leave it only 
the yellow color with the gradient and add thet arrow as

`android:drawableLeft="@drawable/my_arrow"`

as element to your button in xml. That's the best option which I can think of.

Comment: Sorry but why it is wrong? If you mean I stretch the image in two parts vertically, I know it is possible. The 9-patch tool previews show the image stretches correctly.

Comment: just remove the arrow from the background image and use the arrow as another image and set it as `drawableLeft` as I said. If you want to know why you should do it in that way, you can't know how your image will look like in all resolutions and how much should be the left padding of your button so the arrow and text won't be like in the second image.